# Dropping duplicates with custom logic

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
df:
x      y      z1       z2        z3
1.01  2.01   11.415   12.345    100
1.009 2.009  11.415   12.345    100
1.01  2.05   11.415   12.345    100
```

The columns x, and y are measured with some noise. My job is to "de-duplicate" the dataframe w.r.t columns z1, z2, z3 such that entries in columns x and y are not "far" from each other. In the above contrived example the first two rows (rows 1 and 2) are duplicates with the same entry in z columns and x and y reasonably "close". Note that row 3, the final row, also has the same entries but has a y value "far" away from other two rows (2.05 vs 2.01). I have logic to determine what counts as "far" and "close" for columns x and y.

I am looking for a clean way to do this. I have tried windowed applications and using group by etc. but nothing seems to work nicely. Thanks.

Comment: consider switching to categorical using pd.cut, then dropping duplicates there.

Comment: would you be able to elaborate using a snippet? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be create a column labeling the rows where x and y are "close enough" and then dropping duplicates accordingly.

```
df['duplicate'] = df[[x, y]].apply(lambda items: 1*(np.abs(items[0]-items[0]) <= 1.0), axis=1)
df_fltr = pd.concat((df[df.duplicate == 1].drop_duplicates(subset=['z1', 'z2', 'z3']),
                     df[df.duplicate == 0]))
```

Better yet (because it's probably faster) you could use a vectorized approach to create the label:

`df['duplicate'] = ((df.x - df.y).abs() <= 1.0)*1`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.cut`, which converts your objects into binned categories, then find duplicates using .duplicated:

```
z = x.apply(lambda col: pd.cut(col, np.arange(min(col), max(col)+0.01, 0.005), right = False))
z
    x   y   z1  z2  z3
0   [1.009, 1.014)  [2.009, 2.014)  [11.415, 11.42) [12.345, 12.35) [100, 100.005)
1   [1.009, 1.014)  [2.009, 2.014)  [11.415, 11.42) [12.345, 12.35) [100, 100.005)
2   [1.009, 1.014)  [2.049, 2.054)  [11.415, 11.42) [12.345, 12.35) [100, 100.005)

x[~z.duplicated()]

x   y   z1  z2  z3
0   1.01    2.01    11.415  12.345  100
2   1.01    2.05    11.415  12.345  100
```

Change the `np.arange(min(col), max(col)+0.01, 0.005)` to suit your predefined closeness parameters

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works too, but feel the former is a bit more cleaner and pythonic. Thanks again!